# Equal bar widths in ggplot2 histogram using facet_wrap()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data which looks similar to example data below and I am attempting to draw a histogram of the measurement column faceted on the Genotype column. Ultimately I would like the colours of the bars to be conditional on the Genotype and Condition columns.

Crucially Genotype B individuals were never measured under condition L.

This is what the data looks like:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)
DF <- data.frame(Genotype = rep(c("A", "B"), 500), 
                 Condition = sample(c("E", "L"), 1000, replace = T),
                 Measurment = round(rnorm(500,10,3), 0))

DF <- anti_join(DF, filter(DF, Genotype == "B" & Condition != "E"))'

head(DF)

  Genotype Condition Measurment
1        A         L         18
2        A         L          2
3        B         E         18
4        B         E         18
5        B         E         16
6        B         E         16
```

Now I to specify the colours of the bars I thought it easiest to create a new column of hexcodes such that all individuals of Genotype B are one colour, and individuals of Genotype A are a second colour if measured under Condition E and a third colour if measured under Condition L.

```
DF <- DF %>% mutate(colr = ifelse(Genotype == "B", "#409ccd", 
                           ifelse(Condition == "E", "#43cd80", "#ffc0cb")))
```

I can then draw a histogram faceted on the Genotype column like so:

```
ggplot(data=DF, aes(Measurment, fill = Condition)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..count.., fill = colr), position='dodge', binwidth = 1) + 
  facet_wrap(~Genotype, nrow=2) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#409ccd","#ffc0cb","#43cd80")) +
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

and it like like this:

[image: graph]

However as you can see the columns for Genotype B are twice the size of Genotype A. How can I shrink the Genotype B to the same size as Genotype A?

I considered adding dummy entries to my data where Genotype B has Condition L entries but the binning function then counts these as Measurements which is misleading. I also have a version of this using `geom_bar()` but that results in a similar problem. ggplot must have a way of doing this.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this maybe?

```
ggplot(data=DF, aes(Measurment, fill = Condition)) +
  geom_histogram(data=subset(DF, Genotype!="B"),aes(y=..count.., fill = colr), position='dodge', binwidth = 1) + 
  geom_histogram(data=subset(DF, Genotype=="B"),aes(x = Measurment, y=..count.., fill = colr), position=position_nudge(x=0.25), binwidth = 0.5) +
  facet_wrap(~Genotype, nrow=2) + 
  scale_fill_identity() +
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like the following? I assumed by size of the column you meant bar width.

```
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
p1 <- ggplot(data=DF[DF$Genotype=='A',], aes(Measurment, fill = Condition)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..count.., fill = colr), position='dodge', binwidth = 1) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#43cd80","#ffc0cb")) +
  theme(legend.position="none")
p2 <- ggplot(data=DF[DF$Genotype=='B',], aes(Measurment, fill = Condition)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..count.., fill = colr), binwidth = 0.5, boundary = 1) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#409ccd")) +
  theme(legend.position="none")
grid.arrange(p1, p2)
```

[image]

Comment: Close, but I want the blue bars to be directly below the pink ones. I was hoping for a facet_wrap() solution.